# Signs vs. Signage

Tags: meaning, signage

Native speaker here, and recently I got into a discussion with my pops about the word 'signage'. His contention is that the word 'signage' is entirely superfluous and is only used as a $5 alternative to the word 'signs'. My contention is that there may be (maybe not, too) a valid reason for using signage instead of signs.

According to Merriam-Webster, the word signage was first seen in 1976, which makes me think he may be correct - after all, if it were grammatically correct, one would think it would have appeared alongside the word signs.

If it is grammatically correct, why would signage have taken so long to appear? Is there something inherently different in how we think about our signs in modern times?

Comment: Have you looked up the definitions? I went to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.com) and got drastically different meanings. There's a bit of overlap, but they are distinct words.

Comment: Merriam webster defines signage simply as "signs... or a system of such signs" http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/signage . I guess my question is more related to usage / history. When is either appropriate?

Comment: Based off the definitions from MW, signage refers to the conveyance of the message--icons, words, arrows--whereas sign refers to the display itself. [In this image](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-218829331/stock-photo-airport-information-sign.html?src=-ChedAiAR6DEczTwL2sz3g-1-30), the entire yellow block is a "sign" whereas the planes, people, arrow, and words are "signage". In certain contexts, signage and sign can be interchangeable, but they have their own distinct meanings.

Comment: VampDuc, can you reply as an answer instead of a comment so I can (possibly) accept your answer later? :)

Comment: OED's first citation is actually [1949](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/179517?redirectedFrom=signage#eid). They define ***signage*** as *Signs **collectively,** esp. **commercial** signs or those on **public display**; the **design and arrangement** of these.* Presumably the need for a more specific term has increased in recent decades, but I really don't see where "grammaticality" comes into it.

Comment: One way to differentiate is that "signs" is the plural of "sign" while "signage" is a mass noun (with the usual implications).

Comment: The nominalizing -_age_ derivational suffix has a number of uses (or usages), some of which mean the same thing as a plural event nominal (like _signage/signs_). But many others don't; there's a lot of variation. Try these: _herbage
cubage
brigandage
bondage
poundage
yardage
cordage
mileage
acreage
leafage
roofage
wharfage
serfage
baggage
luggage
roughage
verbiage
foliage
carriage
marriage
leakage
breakage
package
wreckage
blockage
linkage
shrinkage
corkage
vassalage
assemblage
tutelage
persiflage
camouflage
spoilage_. [More words available here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/speculum.txt).

Comment: @john-lawler, please add as an answer so I can upvote. Very helpful!

Comment: To make it short, signage is the intent and sign is the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off the definitions from Merriam-Webster ([Signage](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/signage); [Sign](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sign)), signage refers to the conveyance of the message—icons, words, arrows—whereas sign refers to the display itself.

[image]

In the above image, the entire yellow block is a "sign" whereas the planes, people, arrow, and words are "signage".

In certain contexts, signage and sign can be interchangeable, but they have their own distinct meanings.

Comment: Good answer, but in my subsequent reading I've been given the impression that signage could mean the specific system in which the signs are laid out - 'good signage' meaning a system of signs that is laid out in a sensible way (i.e., spread along a route at each turn, as opposed to just a jumble in a lobby). Could it mean both?

Comment: @crypticsymbols Yes, it is the same thing. A sign is a "thing" containing information whereas signage defines the "conveyance" of the information. Another example is traveling down the road, seeing various billboards for "Worlds Best Pie" at 50 miles, 40 miles, 25 miles, 15 miles, 5 miles, and TURN RIGHT HERE FOR PIE. The _billboards are_ signs and the _use of the signs is_ signage.